# How to write better async/await + promise code?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

So this is how it looks.

```
function async doAction() {
    await this.waitForData();
    // do some other things after data loads
    // when data loads it's available in this.data
}

function waitForData() {
    if (!this.promise) {
        this.promise = new Promise(res => this.promiseResolve = res);
        return this.promise;
    }
    else {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
}

function loadData(data) {
    //some things
    this.data = data;

    if (this.promiseResolve) {
        this.promiseResolve(this.data);
    }
}
```

It works pretty fine, `doAction` waits for data load and then action starts. But it's pretty much code, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Where is `loadData` called? Where is `doAction` called? Is `waitForData` only called from `doAction`? Are all of these `function`s actually methods of a class?

Comment: yes they are. `loadData` is called in some other place which is not connected with `doAction`

Comment: Can `loadData` be called multiple times? You say it's not connected to `doAction`, but are they always called in sequence?

Comment: What's the purpose of `promiseResolve`?

Comment: Yes it can. But when promise is resolved it cannot be resolved again, right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it, but `loadData` is a `success` of an async function

Comment: …but that async function that calls `loadData` is still independent from `doAction`, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some bugs with concurrent calls or calls in unexpected sequence. I would do

```
function waitForData() {
    if (!this.promise) {
        this.promise = new Promise(res => this.promiseResolve = res);
    }
    return this.promise;
}

function loadData(data) {
    //some things
    this.data = data;

    if (this.promiseResolve) {
        this.promiseResolve(this.data);
        this.promiseResolve = null;
    } else {
        this.promise = Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
}
```

But other than that, yes this is the way to go for connecting two independent things by promises.